# How do I list the paths of the files that were changed in a commit?

Tags: node.js, git, nodegit

I can currently walk a particular branch to get the details of the commits (i.e. author, timestamp, etc.) but I would like to also get the files that were affected by the commit.

What I have tried:

```
commit.getDiff().then(function(arrayDiff) {
  arrayDiff.forEach(function(diff) {
    diff.patches().then(function(patches) {
      patches.forEach(function(patch) {
        console.log("diff", patch.oldFile().path(), patch.newFile().path());
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The problem seems to be at `diff.patches().then(function(patches)`. I can add logging statements and see that the `arrayDiff` has items in it, that the foreach is working for it, but my code never reaches `patches.forEach`.

**What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to get the path of the files that were part of a commit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the current version of NodeGit on NPM (0.4.1) but unfortunately the docs are pointed to the next version which normalized all of those calls to be promises.

Can you try this on master? If you need to stay on 0.4.1 then `patches()` should return the array of patches and not the promise.

Comment: It was easier for me to modify to my code to use an arrray. When it breaks with the next version I'll be sure to swap it back. Thanks, I was driving my self crazy with this. Is there a way to get to the docs for a specific version by chance?

Comment: There's a lot of API changes in the next version. libgit2 had a big update which changed a lot. Just so you know.